# EF PostgreeSQL array_append

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql, ef-postgresql

I want append a item to column with type int[].
i see PostgreSQL document with array_append can do this.
but how can we do this with EF Core? (i use Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This currently isn't supported (the list of supported array translations can be found [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html)).

In the meantime, as a workaround you can use [raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) to express your query directly in SQL, and possibly compose additional LINQ operators over that.

EDIT: opened https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2026 to track, this should be doable for 6.0.

Comment: Update: I've implemented this, it will be available in 6.0.0-rc.2

Answer (score 0):

raw SQL Query:

```
var sql= $"UPDATE public.\"TableName\" SET \"ArrayColumnName\" = array_append(\"ArrayColumnName\", {value}) WHERE  ... ;";//fill ... with your condition

var result =await  _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql) ;//return int
```